# Is Poisson model in R appropriate here?

Tags: r, poisson-regression

I am graphing a dataset in R that is whether a customer makes an unplanned purchase which can take values from 0-infinity, against customer path length which may take only positive values. The Unplanned purchase represents the unit measure of unplanned purchases made by a customer (This is UNPCATEGORY).

I have used R to model this by using the following code:

```
fit2 <- glm(PLD$UNPCATEGORY+1 ~PATHLEN, data=PLD, family=poisson(link=log))
```

Is it appropriate for me to adjust UNPCATEGORY by +1 here? I assumed it was necessary since I am using a long link. Additionally, since UNPCATEGORY can take these 0 values is it more appropriate to use a NB model?

Here is my model:

```
    Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 2.113e-01  7.362e-02   2.871  0.00409 ** 
PLD$PATHLEN 6.320e-04  3.643e-05  17.345  < 2e-16 ***
```

Comment: You don't have to add 1 in the response. A Poisson regression does not model the log of the response but rather tries to express log(E(Y)) as a linear function of the covariables. So the log is around the expectation, not around the response. Another question is if Poisson regression is really appropriate in your setting. What exactly is the response standing for?

Comment: "whether a customer makes a purchase" within a particular category is 0/1 (they do or they don't). Why would you use Poisson for that? Or do you mean you're aggregating across categories? (which would still not be Poisson --  I'd think Poisson-binomial might describe it) ... Please clarify what your response is.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, I should've made this clear. The categories represent a unit measure of how many unplanned products were purchased. It is simply the number of products purchased, therefore a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one uses Poisson regression when the outcome of interest is a count. If I am reading your model, your outcome of interest is a collection of categories that are coded numerically, and the numbers have no intrinsic meaning.

You could model whether the customer made a purchase (use a Logistic Regression), or model the choice of category (multinomial logit).

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, I should've made this clear. The categories represent a unit measure of how many unplanned products were purchased. It is simply the number of products purchased, therefore a numerical value.